# Is there a way to find out the URL of a Java Spark Web Server?

Tags: java, url, spark-java

I've been developing a Java Spark(http://sparkjava.com) Web service to be accessed futurely by an Android app.

For testing reasons i've been accessing it from local means(i.e. Browser). Now that the Android app is prepared  to start sending data to the server there's a roadblock: the URL for the data to be sent.

I sense that it will be a IP:port based URL such as "0.0.0.0:4567/insert", the one accessible when I test it locally.

Does the url need to be some IP address from http://www.whatsmyip.org concatenated with the port, that i know is 4567 and the desired route?

EDIT:

I believe to have solved this.
To anyone with this problem, there's an instruction ipAddress(String), that lets you define the desired address. Will now test if I can remotely access this.

Comment: Will you run the app with the embedded Jetty server? Will you have any other webserver acting as a proxy for you Java app?

Comment: k. liakos: The idea is the Android app will send data remotely to the webserver, they'll be two different "modules"

Comment: Do you have any experience with web applications overall? Do you understand what a webserver is? Webservers are for example Apache, Nginx or IIS.